# Is there a way to add two text values one above and one below bar chart? In ios danielgindi charts

Tags: objective-c, swift, bar-chart, ios-charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVu7g.png)

is there a way to add two text values one above and one below  bar chart as shown in the image

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two (and more) different values using **\n** symbol as delimiter on data preparing step. Or use *IAxisValueFormatter* for more control. Something like this for example:

```
extension ChartController: IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if axis is XAxis {
            return "Sting 1\nString2"
        } 
    }

}
```